# Drawing Connecting Lines ("Great Arcs") on a D3 Symbol Map

Tags: d3.js, charts, great-circle

I am using **Version 4** of the [D3 Library](https://d3js.org/) and am, to this point, unable to draw connecting lines between points on a [Symbol Map](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html). In the example, from an earlier version of the library, drawing connecting lines is accomplished with this code:

```
// calculate the Great Arc between each pair of points
var arc = d3.geo.greatArc()
  .source(function(d) { return locationByAirport[d.source]; })
  .target(function(d) { return locationByAirport[d.target]; });

[snip]

// Draw the Great Arcs on the Chart.
g.selectAll("path.arc")
    .data(function(d) { return linksByOrigin[d.iata] || []; })
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return path(arc(d)); });
```

The comments are mine (and could be wrong), the code is from the Symbol Map example, above.

In version 4, `d3.geo.greatArc()` [appears to have been deprecated](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1021) in favor of `d3.geoDistance()`. I cannot say this for sure, but I can find no reference to `greatArc` in version 4. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to set up a call to `geoDistance()` to get the same information that `greatArc()` used to return. The [documentation provided for `geoDistance()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoDistance) is not enough for me to understand how to use it.

So, my question is: How do I draw lines between points (lat/long pairs) on a D3 Symbol Chart using Version 4 of the library?

Comment: The example you link to is actually `d3` version 2!  Do you really care about [great arcs or great arc distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).  Or are you just trying to draw lines between two sets of latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: I didn't realize that it was a v2 example. I have edited my question accordingly. I am just trying to draw lines between two sets of latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation on [Spherical Shapes](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#spherical-shapes) has it:

> To generate a [great arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) (a segment of a great circle), simply pass a GeoJSON LineString geometry object to a [d3.geoPath](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoPath). D3’s projections use great-arc interpolation for intermediate points, so there’s no need for a great arc shape generator.

This means you can render great arcs by creating GeoJSON [`LineString`](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring) objects containing the coordinates of both the start and end point in its `coordinates` property:

```
{type: "LineString", coordinates: [[lonStart, latStart], [lonEnd, latEnd]]}
```

As this is a standard GeoJSON object, a path generator ([d3.geoPath](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoPath)) will then be able to digest it and – using the underlying projection – do great-arc interpolation to create a projected great arc.

For a working demo have a look at Mike Bostock's [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400) built using D3 v4, which is similar to your example. Note, that the Block uses [`MultiLineString`](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#multilinestring) objects to account for multiple flights to and from any particular airport, which can be fed to the path generator the same way as the simple `LineString` objects, though. The example creates the great arcs like follows:

1. While reading in the airports' information create empty `MultiLineString` objects for every airport:

   ```
   d3.queue()
       .defer(d3.csv, "airports.csv", typeAirport)

   // ...

   function typeAirport(d) {
     d[0] = +d.longitude;
     d[1] = +d.latitude;
     d.arcs = {type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: []};
     return d;
   }
   ```
2. Iterate over the flights and push the coordinates of the source and target airport to the `coordinates` property of the `MultiLineString` object.

   ```
   flights.forEach(function(flight) {
     var source = airportByIata.get(flight.origin),
         target = airportByIata.get(flight.destination);
     source.arcs.coordinates.push([source, target]);
     target.arcs.coordinates.push([target, source]);
   });
   ```
3. Create a suitable geo path generator.

   ```
   var path = d3.geoPath()
       .projection(projection)
       .pointRadius(2.5);
   ```
4. Bind the data making it available for the path generator to actually draw the great arcs.

   ```
   var airport = svg.selectAll(".airport")
     .data(airports)
     .enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "airport");

   // ...

   airport.append("path")
       .attr("class", "airport-arc")
       .attr("d", function(d) { return path(d.arcs); });  // great arc's path
   ```

Comment: which projection should I use?  I tried to add the great arcs to the map, but they do not align: ``
    var map = L.map('d3_plot_container').setView([41.7500, -72.6358], 3);
``
        var mapLink = 
            '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,zoomControl:true
            }).addTo(window.map);
        L.svg().addTo(map); 
``